# For Two Bodies At Rest, How Many $g$'s Before General Relativity Matters?

Tags: general-relativity, acceleration, estimation, approximations

I'm an EE, so please forgive if this question is dumb.

It is my understanding that in GR, acceleration can curve spacetime, even if the velocity between two bodies is not comparable to the speed of light.

Let's say two bodies are at rest relative to one another.

At time $t=0$, there is a large acceleration between them, even though their relative distance and velocity have not changed noticeably.

Here is my question:

In order to warp spacetime noticeably, how many $g$'s must there be between the two bodies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order to warp spacetime noticeably, how many G's must there be between the two bodies?

You probably mean "how many $g$'s" ($g$ meaning the [gravitational acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_acceleration)),
not "how many $G$'s" ($G$ meaning Newton's [gravitational constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant)).

When general relativity becomes important, is not a matter
of the gravitational acceleration $g$,
but of the [gravitational potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_potential) $V$.

If $V \ll c^2$ (where $c$ is the speed of light),
then you can safely use Newton's classical theory of gravity
as a good approximation.
Otherwise (i.e. for larger potentials $V$) you need to
use general relativity instead.

Comment: Thank you Thomas!